# Connect via ODBC to Progress 9.1D database running on SCO Unix

Tags: odbc

We are looking to take a database dump of a really old database from a Progress DB system we have running at our office, however we've come up against a brick wall trying to connect to the system using an ODBC driver from [OpenLink](http://www.openlinksw.com/).

here's a rundown of the setup.

We have a SCO Unix system running a Progress 9.1D database server (circa 15 - 20 years old), it has the SQL listener / system enabled and running on the server. if we login to the system locally using Putty we can use the Unix app that was written for the db to connect to the DB and retrieve/process data etc.

I appreciate this doesn't help to resolve a problem with an ODBC network connection but I figured I'd mention it to clarify that we can access the DB and query data.

We are trying to connect to the server using 2 machines (Win7 PRO and win 8.1 PRO), using the [OpenLink Single tier ODBC driver for Progress 9.1D (32bit)](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-progress-st/).

All of my attempts to access the database from the PC so far have given the following errors --

```
SQL State : S1000
[OpenLink][ODBC]Unable to allocate server handle

SQL State : 08004
[OpenLink][ODBC][Driver]Connection rejected by data source
```

I am using the following parameters when trying to connect.

```
session options : -d mdy
database options : -N tcp -H <hostname> -db <db location> -S 3030
table view : <blank>
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated on this problem for us as its really making us scratch our heads.

Comment: For future reference, OpenLink (my employer) focused resources such as [installation/configuration guides](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/PreinstallProgressLiteWin32), [public support forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), and [confidential support cases](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp) often provide faster and more accurate assistance than generic sites like SF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Progress 9 has two modes — SQL[-92] and 4GL/ABL/SQL-89. Your ODBC driver may be trying to use the SQL connection, which might be running on a different port from 4GL. Your server could also be setup to only run one or the other, or have limited connections, etc.

I would look on the server at the `databasename.lg` file and see what entries it shows when you tried to connect. It will give you more relevant information than the ODBC driver will give.

Comment: turned out to be the connection string we were using was incorrect, after a lot more head scratching and testing we managed to find the right sql port and connect successfully.

Comment: The connection attributes do need to sync with the details found in the `.lg` file, but OpenLink produces ODBC/JDBC/ADO.NET drivers to connect to each face of a Progress 9.1 hybrid engine -- both the SQL[-92] and the 4GL/ABL/SQL-89.